# Openstack-Ironic: which address is 'ssh_address' driver option referring to in a ironic node with pxe_ssh driver

Tags: openstack

When creating an ironic node with pxe_ssh as the driver, which address is the 'ssh_address' driver option referring to.
Below is the command from devstack.log

```
ironic node-create --driver pxe_ssh -p cpus=1 -p memory_mb=1024 -p local_gb=10 -p cpu_arch=x86_64 -i deploy_kernel=[[deploy kernel uuid from glance]] -i deploy_ramdisk=[[deploy ramdisk uuid from glance]] -i ssh_virt_type=virsh -i ssh_address=192.168.0.102 -i ssh_port=22 -i ssh_username=stack -i ssh_key_filename=/opt/stack/data/ironic/ssh_keys/ironic_key
```

The address above is the control node ip. How can ironic power_on/power_off the baremetal(virsh in this case) if the address is referring to the control node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/openstack/ironic/blob/master/ironic/drivers/modules/ssh.py#L58

Found the specifications here. Hope it helps

```
REQUIRED_PROPERTIES = {
'ssh_address': _("IP address or hostname of the node to ssh into. "
                 "Required."),
'ssh_username': _("username to authenticate as. Required."),
'ssh_virt_type': _("virtualization software to use; one of vbox, virsh, "
                   "vmware, parallels. Required.")}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the IP address of the node to ssh into. Any required spec can be found out via ironic driver-properties *driver_name*